# Spring - How to build a junit test for a soap service

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit, spring-test-mvc

I'm following the spring guide to create a hello world soap ws. The link below :

https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

I successfully make it work. When i run this command line :

> curl --header "content-type: text/xml" -d
>   @src/test/resources/request.xml http://localhost:8080/ws/coutries.wsdl

I get this response.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns2:getCountryResponse xmlns:ns2="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service"><ns2:country><ns2:name>Spain</ns2:name><ns2:population>46704314</ns2:population><ns2:capital>Madrid</ns2:capital><ns2:currency>EUR</ns2:currency></ns2:country></ns2:getCountryResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Now i'm trying to create a junit test for this service (the controller layer) but it doesn't work.

Here is my unit test :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(CountryEndpoint.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {CountryRepository.class, WebServiceConfig.class})
public class CountryEndpointTest {

    private final String URI = "http://localhost:8080/ws/countries.wsdl";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {


        mockMvc.perform(

                get(URI)
                        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
                        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
                        .content(request)

        )
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    static String request = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\n" +
            "                  xmlns:gs=\"http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service\">\n" +
            "    <soapenv:Header/>\n" +
            "    <soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "        <gs:getCountryRequest>\n" +
            "            <gs:name>Spain</gs:name>\n" +
            "        </gs:getCountryRequest>\n" +
            "    </soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "</soapenv:Envelope>";
}
```

here's the error :

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

I changed the log level to debug and i found this :

```
2020-01-27 18:04:11.880  INFO 32723 --- [           main] c.s.t.e.s.endpoint.CountryEndpointTest   : Started CountryEndpointTest in 1.295 seconds (JVM running for 1.686)
2020-01-27 18:04:11.925 DEBUG 32723 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /ws/countries.wsdl
2020-01-27 18:04:11.929 DEBUG 32723 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/ws/countries.wsdl]
2020-01-27 18:04:11.930 DEBUG 32723 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/ws/countries.wsdl] are [/**]
2020-01-27 18:04:11.930 DEBUG 32723 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/ws/countries.wsdl] are {}
2020-01-27 18:04:11.931 DEBUG 32723 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/ws/countries.wsdl] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@c7a977f]]] and 1 interceptor
```

I tried another solution (below) but it doesn't work either.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebServiceConfig.class, CountryRepository.class})
public class CountryEndpointTest {

    private final String URI = "http://localhost:8080/ws/countries.wsdl";

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    CountryRepository countryRepository;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new CountryEndpoint(countryRepository)).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring doc says :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

> By default, @SpringBootTest will not start a server.

You need to define

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

to RUN the server.

I tried with mockserver, but I can't access to the endpoint (even with WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)

So I did it as follow :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class FacturationEndpointTest {

@Autowired
private WebTestClient webClient;

@Test
public void testWSDL() throws Exception {

    this.webClient.get().uri("/test_service/services.wsdl")
            .exchange().expectStatus().isOk();

}
```

You need to add the following dependency in your pom.xml if you want to use WebTestClient like me :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It works like magic !!! i have to upgrade my spring boot version (i'm in version 1.X.X) to use webflux. thanks for you comment and the solution @bastien

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a spring ws framework to implements your endpoints, please see spring-ws-test. you will find a MockWebServiceClient that mocks a client and tests your endpoint. I propose you to see this example : https://memorynotfound.com/spring-ws-server-side-integration-testing/

this works only for spring web service and not for CXF web services.

Comment: Thanks Badreddine for your response. Unfortunaly the example does not work in my case because i'm using a newer version of spring boot (1.5.6.RELEASE) but the example uses a deprecated version (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-ws?repo=springio-plugins-release).

Comment: another solution could be the RestAssured Framework see Usage : https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage

Answer (score 0):

Please change the `GET` method to `POST`.

```java
mockMvc.perform(

                postURI) // <-- This line!!!
                        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
                        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
                        .content(request)
```

Comment: I changed it but it doesn't seem to solve the issue. I had 404 as status.